# Why does websites use a different domain name for their css, and javascript scripts?

Tags: dns, web

Top websites such as facebook, dropbox, seem to use another domain to load their css, js. Example. fbcdn.net. Whats going on? Why don't they use their own current url?

Answer (score 0):

This is often done for load balancing purposes. Companies can speed up their services by offloading static content to different servers allowing their dynamic content servers to function more efficiently.

I don't work at any of those companies, but I've used that strategy successfully in the past.

Comment: elaborate on Companies can speed up their services by offloading static content to different servers allowing their dynamic content servers to function more efficiently

Comment: Static content is often served off of a plain web server like apache or IIS because it can be retrieved and sent back to the customer very very quickly. Dynamic content (something that has to be generated from the customer's request) often takes much longer (in machine terms, hopefully still in the ms ranges) so it is better to dedicate bigger, faster boxes to that content and less powerful machines to servicing static.